# Add user location marker to existing gmap

Tags: google-maps, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-gmap

I am using Drupal 7 - Location, GMap module. I have a view that renders the result in a gmap. Everything works fine here and I get all the markers. Now I need a Find My location button which shows the users current location and adds a marker to the existing map.
Google Map Api V3 always works on a newly created map and I couldn't find a function which returns an existing map in the current page.

Gmap module provides a JS function - Drupal.gmap.getMap('ur-map-id') which is supposed to return a pointer to the map whose id is given. But this did not work.

Could someone please guide me as to how I should go about this? Can I get it work with Google Maps API? I need to retain the original map with all its markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having this issue as well, you can put this jquery code in for it to actually centre around your current location - but no marker is added. Just add it anywhere in your theme,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(function($) {
$.extend({
initialize: function () {
var m = Drupal.gmap.getMap('auto1map');
if (m.map && m.markersready) {
$.setCoords();
}
else {
m.bind('markersready', function(data) {
$.setCoords();
});
}
},
setCoords: function () {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
var gmap = Drupal.gmap.getMap('auto1map').map;
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lng = position.coords.longitude;
gmap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
gmap.setZoom(13);
});
}
});
$.initialize();
});

});
```

Now you can centre your map around your location and now I need to figure out a way to place a marker down at this location.

Comment: Thanks. However, the map is also available as m['map'], where m is as you've mentioned Drupal.gmap.getMap(map-id).

Answer (score 2):

Here's something for reference.

```
if (typeof(navigator.geolocation) !== 'undefined') {
  var showUserOnMap = function(position) {
    var map = Drupal.gmap.getMap('gmap-auto1map-gmap0');
    if (typeof(map) !== 'undefined' && map !== false) {
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      var marker = {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        markername: Drupal.t('You'),
        opts: {
          title: Drupal.t('You')
        }
      }
      marker.opts.position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      marker.opts.map = map.map;
      Drupal.gmap.factory.marker(marker.opts);
    }
  };

  // Get the current location
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showUserOnMap);
}
```